# Gif not fading out despite calling .fadeOut command

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a gif that I have to fade out after the page loads, but I'm not having much luck.

I want the overlay, which has a white background and the gif, to fade into transparency after everything else on the page is loaded and ready to be seen.

Below is my code, and also a link to a page where I've been testing it:

[Link to test code](https://jsfiddle.net/JoeFerris/pnzqau7c/1/)

any ideas?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-cRpWjoSOw5KcyIOaZNo4i6fZ9tKPhYYb6i5T9RSVJG8="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="overlay">
<img src="https://www.isostech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/loader.gif" alt="Loading" /><br/>
Loading...
</div>
Hello World!

<script>
$(window).load(function(){
$('#overlay').fadeOut();
});
</script>
```

And the CSS:

```
#overlay {
    background-color: white;
    color: #666666;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25%;
}
```

Comment: You included two versions of jQuery. Remove one and it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/pnzqau7c/4/

Comment: perfect. Can you put that below so I can mark you as right?

Comment: Thats ok - I would just delete the question as the problem was caused by an oversight that's not likely to help anyone in the future.

Comment: Wait no! Don't! Even if you don't accept my answer, let me outline what I found since I think many will encounter this soon with the new jQuery version

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I think that this could be helpful to let people know that the `.load()` event is no longer supported after jQuery v3.0, which is why it wasn't working in the first place. https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: @HunterTurner that's true, however there are plenty of questions answering the '$.load is not a function` error, and no one is going to find that answer by searching for 'why does my gif not fade out'

Comment: They might. Do not remove knowledge because it has a slim use case. Google might also pick up words int the answers and so they can be found that way

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, you have a point.. Haha.

Comment: This has got nothing whatsoever to do with the deprecation of the `load` method in jQuery 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use multiple versions of jQuery. If you either delete the include for jQuery 3, or make the following change, it will work.

I recently contributed to [document-ready handlers](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) in the SO:Docs which applies here and I think many will not realize as they switch to jQuery 3.

> ```
> jQuery(function($) {
>   // Run when document is ready
>   // $ (first argument) will be internal reference to jQuery
>   // Never rely on $ being a reference to jQuery in the global namespace
> });
> ```
>
> All other document-ready handlers are deprecated in jQuery 3.0.

Using that doc-ready handler will work even if you leave both jQuery includes in the code.